# Laravel 5 + MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

I have a problem with using MongoDB in Laravel 5 using [Laravel MongoDB](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb). MongoDB PHP driver installed. Any operations with MongoDB returns 500 error.
My example:

ExampleModel:

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;
class ExampleModel extends Eloquent {
   protected $connection = 'mongodb';
   protected $collection = 'polls';
}
```

ExampleModelController:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\ExampleModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ExampleModelController extends Controller {

    public function test()
   {
      $test = new ExampleModel();
      $test->create(["foo" => "bar"]);
      return 'ok';
   }

}
```

Route to test in ExampleModelController works good.

```
Route::get('test', 'ExampleModelController@test');
```

This code returns error 500 (testing in Postman Chrome extension).

I used MongoDB with another project (with node.js) and everything works good, so MongoDB installed properly.

Any idea 'bout this problem?

P.S. No logs in storage/logs/ about this error.

OS: Mac OS X 10.10.2

Comment: It was my fall. Problem solved with db.createUser() (not addUser) to needle database

Comment: Please post the problem solving solution as an answer and accept it, so this question won't appear as unanswered. Thank you.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois done, thanks for advice )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was my fall. Problem solved with

```
db.createUser({user: "username", pwd: "secret", roles: ["readWrite"]})
```

in mongo console
NOT addUser method

Comment: As addUser method is deprecated, Even when you run this cmd in mongo shell it will ask you to use createUser